# Cplex code to formulate conditional constraint

Tags: cplex, opl

How can I formulate this conditional constraint for cplex :

```
if (S[i][t] <=0 ) then   S[i][t+1]=S[i][t]-livraison[i][t]+order[i][t]
```

with  `S[i][t]` and `order[i][t]` are a decision variables and
`livraison[i][t]` is a known parameter

Answer (score 1):

```
(S[i][t] <=0 ) =>   (S[i][t+1]==S[i][t]-livraison[i][t]+order[i][t]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let check this code

```
{int} part ={1, 2};
{int} time = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

int livraison [part][time] =[[20, 30, 46, 24, 53], [12, 12, 14, 65, 34]];

dvar int S[part][time];
dvar int order[part][time];

int iniS[part] = [0, 0];
int iniorder[part] = [0, 0];

subject to {

forall(i in part, t in time) {
    if (t == 1){
        S[i][t + 1] == iniS[i]-livraison[i][t]+iniorder[i];
    }
    else if (t >= 2){   
        (S[i][t-1] <=0) => (S[i][t] == S[i][t-1]-livraison[i][t-1]+order[i][t-1]);
    }
}
}
```

I hope it can help you, or check this discussion: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014923153

Comment: thanx for your answer @Khái Duy . i have a question it is normal that the program give negative decision variable ??? i foundi this results           S = [[2  -20 1 1 0]
             [2 -12 1 0 -65]];
order = [[0 51 0 0 -2147483647]
             [0 25 0 0 -2147483647]];

Comment: Hi Fati, this depends on your constraint